# Is there a way to disable the month/viewmode button in bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've updated bootstrap from version 3 to 4 and noticed the calendar is overlapping when creating it with js instead of cshtml. There's no need to go back more than a few days so I would like to disable the month button that changes the view mode to months or years. Is there a specific CSS property that I need or would I need to edit a code in the library?

[image: viewmode normal]

[image: viewmode overlapped]

```
function AddDateTimeControl(parent, control, rowIndex, controlIndex) {
    var dateTimeID = "datetimepicker" + controlIndex;

    var tooltipDiv = CreateTooltipDiv();
    var tooltipSpan = CreateTooltipSpan(control.ToolTip);
    var label = CreateControlLabel(control);
    //var icon = CreateIcon('fa-calendar');
    var icon = CreateIcon("calendar-alt-regular");

    tooltipDiv.appendChild(label);
    tooltipDiv.appendChild(icon);
    tooltipDiv.appendChild(tooltipSpan);

    var dateDiv = document.createElement("div");
    dateDiv.classList.add('input-group');
    dateDiv.classList.add('date');
    dateDiv.classList.add('date-time-control');
    dateDiv.style.color = "black";
    dateDiv.id = dateTimeID;

    var dateTextBox = document.createElement("input");
    dateTextBox.type = "text";
    dateTextBox.classList.add("form-control");
    dateTextBox.value = control.RawValues[0];

    MarkElementForSerialization(dateTextBox, rowIndex, control.ID, 0);

    var calControlSpan = document.createElement("span");
    calControlSpan.classList.add('input-group-append'); //input-group-addon?
    //span -> fa-calendar?

    dateDiv.appendChild(dateTextBox);
    dateDiv.appendChild(calControlSpan); //input-group-addon

    parent.appendChild(tooltipDiv);
    parent.appendChild(dateDiv);

    $(dateDiv).datetimepicker();
    $(dateDiv).data("DateTimePicker").sideBySide(true);
    $(dateDiv).data("DateTimePicker").date(new Date(Date.parse(control.RawValues[0])));
    $(dateDiv).data("DateTimePicker").format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm");
    $(dateDiv).data("DateTimePicker").icons({
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
        down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
        previous: "fa fa-chevron-left",
        next: "fa fa-chevron-right",
        today: "fa fa-clock-o",
        clear: "fa fa-trash-o"
    });

    $(dateTextBox).on('click', function() {
        $(dateDiv).data("DateTimePicker").toggle();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up disabling it by disabling the pointer event in the month picker switch.

```
th.picker-switch[title="Select Month"] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That will depend entirely on which datetimepicker component you are using.

[This one](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) lets you set the maximum view:

```
$(dateDiv).datetimepicker({ maxView: 1 })
```

However, it was never updated to support Bootstrap 4.

That picker has since been deprecated in favour of [eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://getdatepicker.com/4/), which has an option to set the *minimum* view, but not the *maximum* view. You would need to dig in to [the code for that version](https://github.com/Eonasdan/tempus-dominus/blob/v4/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js) if you wanted to add that option.

There is a newer version of the Eonasdan picker, now called [tempus dominus](https://github.com/Eonasdan/tempus-dominus), which is currently in alpha. That version provides [options to turn the individual views on or off](https://getdatepicker.com/6/options.html#displayComponents):

```
$(dateDiv).tempusDominus({
   display: {
     viewMode: 'date',
     components: {
       decades: false,
       year: false,
       month: false,
       date: true,
       hours: true,
       minutes: true,
       seconds: false
     }
   }
})
```

Comment: I'm using asp.net, would tempus dominus work with it?

Comment: Yes, I've used it in an MVC5 project with no problems.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you got it to work on asp.net? Did you modify the bundle/config files?